Weights&Biases Show Ground-Truth and Prediction side-by-side
Tried posting on Weights & Biases board but no response. Hope someone here can help:
My runs.summary[‘Validation-Table’] has an image column. When I click on an image I see box-ground-truth(box) and box-predictions(box) and the labels I have. I tried adding a panel with images but images is grayed out in the panel section…
How can I view the ground truth and predicted images with bounding boxes side-by-side?

